# MongoDB Java Driver 3.0 MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

This is the code I'm using to run map reduce on `sourceCollectionName` and to get the output to `targetCollectionName`. But the targetCollectionName is never created.

```
 new MongoClient("localhost").getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(sourceCollectionName)
                .mapReduce(map, reduce)
                    .action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE)
                    .databaseName(dbName)
                    .collectionName(targetCollectionName)
                    .sharded(false);
```

Although I'm able to get output as `MapReduceIterable` and when I iterate this the result is dumped as expected. Is this the right way to do it ?

```
MapReduceIterable mapReduceIterable = new MongoClient("localhost").getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(sourceCollectionName)
                .mapReduce(map, reduce)
                    .action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE)
                    .databaseName(dbName)
                    .collectionName(targetCollectionName)
                    .sharded(false);

for(Object o:mapReduceIterable){
     //Just Iterating makes map reduce to dump output collection
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.  Since the MapReduceIterable is a fluent interface, there must be some way to signal the driver that it's time to actually do the map-reduce, and currently the only way to do that is to start iterating.  If you really don't need the results, and want to short-cut the iteration, you can call the [first()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html#first--) method instead (ignoring the result), which will return the first document and immediately close the cursor on the target collection.

Comment: Yes. This will solve my concern for unnecessary iterations. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
new MongoClient("localhost").getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(sourceCollectionName)
            .mapReduce(map, reduce)
                .action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE)
                .databaseName(dbName)
                .collectionName(targetCollectionName)
                .sharded(false)
                .toCollection()
```